# Can I capture my own pieces?

Tags: rules, checkmate, captures

This may seem like a very amateur question, but I was playing chess with my dad, and when my dad won, I realized that I could've captured my own pawn in order to evade checkmate. I tried to do this move, but my dad said that it was cheating to do so. Can anybody settle this debate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf), §3.1:

> **It is not permitted to move a piece to a square occupied by a piece of the same colour.** If a  piece  moves  to  a  square  occupied  by  an  opponent’s  piece the  latter  is  captured  and  removed  from  the  chessboard  as  part  of  the  same  move.

(emphasis mine).

So you can't capture your own piece.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic Question : You can never capture your piece.

Be it anybody at the start of their Chess Career or even a Professional it may feel sometimes that if I would not have my own Pawn in front of my Piece I could have captured my Opponents Piece or could have started a Great attack but this is where the embodiment of a high level Chess thinking starts .

You need to either sometimes sacrifice your pawn or piece in order to achieve a greater Activity or occupy a file in order to squeeze your Opponent .

Your imagination needs to be extended in order to think deeper to evade that checkmate from your Dad .